# Can't bind IsChecked on RadioButton with custom ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, templatebinding

I have been using a custom RadioButton control with a ToggleButton as the control template. Here's what the xaml looks like:

```
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="tb" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding RadioButton.Content}"
                          PreviewMouseDown="tb_PreviewMouseDown">
            </ToggleButton>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
```

It's been working well, except when I try to either programatically set a button's IsChecked property, or make a binding with it. Then the button that should be checked is visually unresponsive - it doesn't appear to be pressed, and the Aero mouse over effect does not appear. The Clicked event handler still works, and the IsChecked property of both the RadioButton and the ControlTemplate's toggle button are true when I examine their values. Amy I doing something wrong with the binding? Any ideas?

Here's an example of how I use it in the application:

```
<local:RadioToggleButton Content="1Hr" GroupName="Interval" x:Name="oneHrBtn" 
IsChecked="{BindingPath=oneHrBtnIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2 5 3 5" 
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=oneHrBtnIsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue with my custom RadioToggleButton control was being caused by something very weird indeed. I will describe my solution below, not because I expect anyone else to run into this particular problem, but just as an example of a solution that seems unconnected to the problem.

There was a binding on IsEnabled property of the GroupBox containing the button group. This binding seemed to work fine, enabling and disabling all the internal controls when appropriate. But as soon as I removed this binding, the problem I described above disappeared. This is not ideal, but I decided that I had spent too much time on this issue, so I bound the IsEnabled properties of the individual controls to the same property that the GroupBox had been bound to, and now at least I have the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is very strange. The RadioButton class derives from ToggleButton. So effectively you put a button in a button. Are you simply trying to make the RadioButton look like a ToggleButton? If so, why don't you use ToggleButton directly?

If you want to make the RadioButton look like a ToggleButton so you can use the GroupName feature, then you'd have to copy the ToggleButton control template and use that (not embed a ToggleButton in the control template).

You can get the default templates from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Then search for the ToggleButton style and copy it's ControlTemplate.

EDIT:

The following example shows how this can be done. You just need to add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070" />

            <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type RadioButton}" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <theme:ButtonChrome Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}"
                                RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </theme:ButtonChrome>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="RenderDefaulted" Value="true" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="RenderPressed" Value="true" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName="TestGroup">Option 1</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="TestGroup">Option 2</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I was indeed hoping to have toggle buttons with the GroupName property. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out.

Comment: @John - Ok. You'll have to select the appropriate theme, then click Download Sample. That will include the system themes for all native WPF controls.

Comment: @CodeNaked - I got the ControlTemplate from [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx) but when I try to set it as the RadioButton.Template, it throws an error on the element vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups - "The attachable property 'VisualStateGroups' was not found in 'VisualStateManager'. I've looked and seen numerous other complaints about this error, and it seems to be a VS issue. One discussion said the code will compile anyway, but mine does not.

Comment: @John - What theme are you using? Also are you targeting .NET 4 or earlier?

Comment: @John - And what theme? Aero?

Comment: @CodeNaked - Yeah, it has to be Aero.

Comment: @John - I updated my answer with an example. Not sure where you got the VisualStateManager stuff, as that's not included in the system themes.

Comment: @CodeNaked - I was able to compile the application after making this change, but unfortunately it did not fix my issue. I created a sample application using the code you provided, and it worked as expected; I could both bind and assign a true value to the RadioToggleButton. It looks like there's something else at work in my application. What it is, I can't begin to guess. If I figure it out, and it seems like it would be relevant to others, I will update here. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @John - Keep in mind you can only have 1 implicit Style applied at a time. So if you have another implicit Style for the RadioButton, then that may be taking precedence. Also, if you set RadioButton.Style explicitly, then that would take precedence over the implicit Styles.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a `RadioButton` which looks like a `ToggleButton`, you can actually implicitly refer to ToggleButton's style as a static resource by its type:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
```

This seems to work because RadioButton is descended from ToggleButton. So you can't, for example, use `{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}`.

I'm not able to track down any documentation for using an `x:Type` as a resource for `Style`; I'd be interested to see it, if anyone out there knows where to look.

Comment: @Drew eh? OP tried to make a RadioButton which looks like a ToggleButton, but couldn't bind to IsChecked. I've shown a technique for creating a RadioButton which looks like a ToggleButton and allows bindings on IsChecked.

Comment: Yep - if you think the last para is inappropriate, feel free to edit it out. WPF is full of things that are like "I know this works but I have no idea *how*".

Comment: yeah, sorry. Some of us spend a lot of time looking at a thousand answers a day and can't tell at the end if it is in fact a question. Some are both. So my eyes and brain are yielding poor performance at the moment. Thanks for sharing.